# Azure Insights: webapp request time

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-linux, azure-performancecounters

I have enabled http request logging for my webapp in Azure insights. I don't understand there is such a large response time disparity between identical requests, received just a few seconds or a few minutes apart. A log example with three records:

```
{ "time": "2022-07-20T06:08:41.7548330Z", "EventTime": "2022-07-20T06:08:41.7548330Z", "resourceId": "***", "properties": "{\"CsHost\":"***",\"CIp\":\"195.235.205.153\",\"SPort\":\"80\",\"CsUriStem\":\"\\/mensajes\",\"CsUriQuery\":\"desde=20220705T125027\",\"CsMethod\":\"GET\",\"TimeTaken\":1426,\"ScStatus\":\"200\",\"Result\":\"Success\",\"CsBytes\":\"976\",\"ScBytes\":\"302\",\"UserAgent\":\"RestSharp 104.2.0.0\",\"Cookie\":\"--\",\"CsUsername\":\"\",\"Referer\":\"\",\"ComputerName\":\"RD501AC5BF5D04\"}", "category": "AppServiceHTTPLogs", "EventStampType": "Stamp", "EventPrimaryStampName": "waws-prod-am2-325", "EventStampName": "waws-prod-am2-325d", "Host": "RD501AC5BF5D04", "EventIpAddress": "1*.*.*.*"}

{ "time": "2022-07-20T06:09:42.2283150Z", "EventTime": "2022-07-20T06:09:42.2283150Z", "resourceId": "***", "properties": "{\"CsHost\":"***",\"CIp\":\"195.235.205.153\",\"SPort\":\"80\",\"CsUriStem\":\"\\/mensajes\",\"CsUriQuery\":\"desde=20220705T125027\",\"CsMethod\":\"GET\",\"TimeTaken\":279,\"ScStatus\":\"200\",\"Result\":\"Success\",\"CsBytes\":\"976\",\"ScBytes\":\"302\",\"UserAgent\":\"RestSharp 104.2.0.0\",\"Cookie\":\"--\",\"CsUsername\":\"\",\"Referer\":\"\",\"ComputerName\":\"RD501AC5BF5D04\"}", "category": "AppServiceHTTPLogs", "EventStampType": "Stamp", "EventPrimaryStampName": "waws-prod-am2-325", "EventStampName": "waws-prod-am2-325d", "Host": "RD501AC5BF5D04", "EventIpAddress": "*.*.*.*"}

{ "time": "2022-07-20T06:10:15.0636460Z", "EventTime": "2022-07-20T06:10:15.0636460Z", "resourceId": "***", "properties": "{\"CsHost\":"***",\"CIp\":\"195.235.205.153\",\"SPort\":\"80\",\"CsUriStem\":\"\\/mensajes\",\"CsUriQuery\":\"desde=20220705T125027\",\"CsMethod\":\"GET\",\"TimeTaken\":2629,\"ScStatus\":\"200\",\"Result\":\"Success\",\"CsBytes\":\"976\",\"ScBytes\":\"302\",\"UserAgent\":\"RestSharp 104.2.0.0\",\"Cookie\":\"--\",\"CsUsername\":\"\",\"Referer\":\"\",\"ComputerName\":\"RD501AC5BF5D04\"}", "category": "AppServiceHTTPLogs", "EventStampType": "Stamp", "EventPrimaryStampName": "waws-prod-am2-325", "EventStampName": "waws-prod-am2-325d", "Host": "RD501AC5BF5D04", "EventIpAddress": "*.*.*.*"}
```

The three requests are the same and therefore trigger the same process on the server side (same endpoint, made from the same origin). The result can be seen in the 'timeTaken' field: **1426ms/279ms/2629ms** Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

***According to [Microsoft-Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/app-service/web-apps-performance-faqs#how-do-i-decrease-the-response-time-for-the-first-request-after-idle-time) it say,***

> If they remain idle for a predetermined amount of time, web apps are by default unloaded. You can activate the Always On feature in Basic and Standard service levels to keep the app constantly loaded.This eliminates longer load times after the app is idle.

Open your Web  app=> Then click on Configuration=>Then click on General settings=> then on.

[image]

***References:***

- [Smart detection - performance anomalies - Azure Monitor | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/proactive-performance-diagnostics#when-would-i-get-a-smart-detection-notification)
- [Exploring performance issues with Azure Application Insights | by Thomas Weiss | Medium](https://medium.com/@thomasweiss_io/exploring-performance-issues-with-azure-application-insights-962386d53237)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i already tried this without success.